# List has no attribute values

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am making a code for prediction of a sentence after the training part. My code till now is something like this

```
import numpy as np
model = Sequential()
l = ['Hello this is police department', 'hello this is 911 emergency']
texts = l.values()
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
model.predict(X)
```

But when I run this, it gives an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-9a0876037e02> in <module>()
      2 model = Sequential()
      3 l = ['Hello this is police department', 'hello this is 911 emergency']
----> 4 texts = l.values()
      5 tokenizer = Tokenizer()
      6 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Why am I getting this error? Also when I pass indices like `l[1]` it gives the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Python lists do not have a .values() method, you are probably confusing it with a pandas DataFrame

Comment: So, should I first convert the list into a dataframe and then pass it?

Comment: No, I never implied that, you can just pass a list to the Tokenizer

Comment: When I pass the list to the tokenizer, it gives the error `ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]]`

Comment: It is working now, I was passing a python array. Converted into a numpy array